# Catching an exception thrown exception in a .Net Core µService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a .Net Core µService in which I call a Java API. I'm trying to handle a specific case where the Java API throws a certain Exception, let's say `ClientNotFoundException`. This exception is accompagnied by the error message `No client was found for the provided id`. The problem is when this exception is caught in .Net Core all I can see is `Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).`. Is there any way to distinguish this exception from a normal 404 one?

Comment: `microservice` is a fashion term. You're calling a service written in Java. If you get a 404 it's probably a REST service, or at least it follows some REST conventions.  *That service* isn't returning what you thought it would. The .NET client has no way of guessing why the service returned a 404 all it knows is what's in the response. Which, by the way, is a perfectly valid response. What you asked wasn't found

Comment: Have you checked the service's documentation to see what it returns? Perhaps it already returns extra information in the body? Although a 404 is pretty clear. If there is no documentation you can use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to inspect the response to see whether there's any more information available.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain well my problem. I wrote both APIs and they both follow REST convetions. The action in the controller of the Java API returns the exception `ClientNotFoundException` which is exactly what I want, so no problem there. This exception has the status code `404` and again that's what I want. In the body of this exception there's a customized error message. The problem here is when my .Net Core API catches this exception somehow the error message isn't in its details

Comment: all I can extract is that this's a `404` response. I want to know if it was  `ClientNotFoundException` or some other type of exceptions.

Comment: You can't know that unless the remote service returns that information. Why don't you ask that service's author? This isn't something that can be answered by anyone else

Comment: In fact, why do you assume that 404 could represent anything other than a missing client? Returning a 404 is the *proper* response when a resource isn't found. When someone asks for eg `https://myApi.myserver.local/client/1234`, the proper response to return if Client ID 1234 is missing is a 404 response.

Comment: Because I have another exception that's thrown by the same action and that has also a status code of `404` and I want to be able to tell them apart in my C# code after they're caught.

Comment: So ask the Java service's author to give you that information. You can't expect a client application, probably at the other side of the globe to be able to read a service's internal exceptions

Comment: But I wrote that action in the Java service, and I set its error message. What I don't understand is why c# exception doesnt read that error message.

Comment: Why should it? You didn't return any exception information, you explicitly returned a 404 with some extra information. *You* have to return whatever information you want. You should probably post a new question about the Java service asking how to return additional information beyond that 404. This has nothing to do with the client